# Changing the tmp folder of mysql

Tags: mysql, tmp

Our Mysql queries use temporary tables which creates temporary files in the process. Currently the files are written to /tmp. How exactly can the path of the temp folder to which mysql writes to be changed?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should edit your my.cnf

```
tmpdir = /whatewer/you/want
```

and after that restart mysql

P.S. Don't forget give write permissions to `/whatewer/you/want` for mysql user

Answer (score 48):

Here is an example to move the mysqld tmpdir from /tmp to /run/mysqld which already exists on Ubuntu 13.04 and is a tmpfs (memory/ram):

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/conf.d/local.cnf
```

Add:

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir = /run/mysqld
```

Then:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Verify:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
```

==================================================================

If you get an error on MySQL restart, you may have AppArmor enabled:

```
sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Add:

```
# Site-specific additions and overrides for usr.sbin.mysqld.
# For more details, please see /etc/apparmor.d/local/README.
/run/mysqld/ r,
/run/mysqld/** rwk,
```

Then:

```
sudo service apparmor reload
```

sources: http://2bits.com/articles/reduce-your-servers-resource-usage-moving-mysql-temporary-directory-ram-disk.html, https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/apparmor_and_mysql

Answer (score 6):

This is answered in the documentation:

[Where MySQL Stores Temporary Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-files.html)

> On Unix, MySQL uses the value of the TMPDIR environment variable as
>   the path name of the directory in which to store temporary files. If
>   TMPDIR is not set, MySQL uses the system default, which is usually
>   /tmp, /var/tmp, or /usr/tmp.
>
> On Windows, Netware and OS2, MySQL checks in order the values of the
>   TMPDIR, TEMP, and TMP environment variables. For the first one found
>   to be set, MySQL uses it and does not check those remaining. If none
>   of TMPDIR, TEMP, or TMP are set, MySQL uses the Windows system
>   default, which is usually C:\windows\temp.

Comment: The other answers are much better since they explain how to set `tmpdir` in the MySQL configuration file instead of relying upon environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

if you dont have apparmor or selinux issues, but still get errorcode 13's:

mysql must be able to access the full path. I.e. all folders must be mysql accessible, not just the one you intend in pointing to.

example, you try using this in your mysql configuration: `tmp = /some/folder/on/disk`

```
# will work, as user root:
mkdir -p /some/folder/on/disk
chown -R mysql:mysql /some

# will not work, also as user root:
mkdir -p /some/folder/on/disk
chown -R mysql:mysql /some/folder/on/disk
```

Answer (score 3):

**This maybe helpful for MySql with AppArmor**

stop mysql :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Create directory called */somewhere/tmp*

**Edit Config:**

`sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf`   # or perhaps `sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

**change**

> tmpdir = /somewhere/tmp/

**Then**

```
sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

**Add**

```
# Allow data dir access
  /somewhere/ r,
  /somewhere/** rwk,
```

> sudo chown -R root:root /somewhere

> sudo chmod -R 1777 /somewhere

Restart

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload

 sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `TMPDIR` environment variable.

In some situations (Docker in my case) it's more convenient to set an environment variable than to update a config file.

Answer (score 0):

Works for 5.7 on centos 8

```
mkdir /tmp/1 /tmp/1

semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/tmp/1(/.*)?"
                   
restorecon -Rv /tmp/1

semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/tmp/2(/.*)?"

restorecon -Rv /tmp/2

to my.cnf tmpdir=/tmp/1:/tmp/2

sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a MariaDB user, all this above apply, by don't forget to unlock the "home" protection by doing this.

```
touch /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.conf
nano /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.conf
```

Inside override.conf put this content and save.

```
[Service]
ProtectHome=false
```

Then run the following commands :

```
systemctl daemon-reload
/scripts/restartsrv_mysql
```

After restarting mysql, the variables can be checked by :

```
mysqladmin variables|grep tmp
```