# Changing MySQL 5.0's tmp folder within my.ini in Windows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server (version 5.0.67) running on Windows 7. While I was working with hibernate within Eclipse, I got the following error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't create/write to file 'C:\Windows\TEMP#sql_e9c_0.MYI' (Errcode: 17)

I tried to configure the TmpPath of MySQL and set Systemparameters to TMPDIR:

```
TEMP=C:\Users\JDD09~1.HER\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\JDD09~1.HER\AppData\Local\Temp
TMPDIR=C:\tmp\tmpdir
```

Within my.ini, I made the following change:

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir=C:\tmp\tmpdir
```

However, now MySQL aborts when it tries to start up.

I've read this thread ([Changing the tmp folder of mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990887/changing-the-tmp-folder-of-mysql)), but it didn't help. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to make sure you are using forward slashes '/' instead of backward slashes '\'. This worked for me, so you would use this line:

tmpdir=C:/tmp/tmpdir

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir="C:\tmp\tmpdir"
```

and make sure that path `C:\tmp\tmpdir` must exist in the system.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual for Mysql 5.0 as regard 'TMPDIR': [5.0/en/windows-installation.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.0/en/windows-installation.html). The default is to use the windows temporary directory.

If you decide to define it. Then it must be a valid directory. It will not create it.

My recommendation, for a 'development' system on a local pc is not bother changing it. 
If you are not sure then delete the entry from 'my.ini'. This will use the default settings which should be ok to get you started.

ps. i use 'mysql' on windows.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-files.html):

> On Windows, MySQL checks in order the values of the TMPDIR, TEMP, and TMP environment variables. For the first one found to be set, MySQL uses it and does not check those remaining. If none of TMPDIR, TEMP, or TMP are set, MySQL uses the Windows system default, which is usually C:\windows\temp.
>
> If the file system containing your temporary file directory is too small, you can use the mysqld --tmpdir option to specify a directory in a file system where you have enough space.
>
> The --tmpdir option can be set to a list of several paths that are used in round-robin fashion. Paths should be separated by colon characters (:) on Unix and semicolon characters (;) on Windows.

Edit the file `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini`

Add the following line, under `[mysqld]`

```ini
[mysqld]
tmpdir=C:/tmp/tmpdir
```

Restart MySQL service under Windows services.

Change can be verified by the following commands in windows prompt

```bash
mysql -uroot -p -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir'"
```

Comment: I don't see what this answer adds beyond previous answers left 7 years prior.