# mysql error code 3 error writing file (errcode 28)

Tags: mysql, tmp

I know this question has been asked before but I could not fix my problem yet so far after finding answer here and there. I am really frustrated so I tried to ask again here.

I have a table with 76 million rows (`newpaper_type1_ACD`) and I wanna join them with another table with around 7 million rows (`bigdatasetauthorseparated`).

The query is as follows:

```
insert into newpaper_type1_ADE 
(paperkeyA, paperkeyD, authorE)
select a.paperkeyA, a.paperkeyD, b.author
from newpaper_type1_ACD_notempty a
left join bigdatasetauthorseparated b
on a.paperkeyD = b.paperkey
order by b.paperkey, b.author;
```

The `paperkey` is indexed already.

I have tried to execute same query before but in smaller data and it worked. But now it always stopped after 3800 second.

I tried to change this also but it did not work:

```
set global tmp_table_size = 134217728;
set global max_heap_table_size = 134217728;
```

And I noticed that mysql uses the temporary table by default in `C:/windows/temp`. I tried to change the path to `TEMP` and `TMP` in `environmental variable setting` into another hard drive but it also did not work.

My C drive has `201GB` of free space. and my E and F drive has around `9TB` of free space. My OS is Windows Server 2012.

Some article said I should change `my.cnf` file and change the `tmpdir` location but I could not find this file. I have `my.ini` file but i did not see any `tmpdir` variable inside.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**: 
Even if I have changed the Windows Environment Variable Setting into another hard drive (`F:/temp`), when I check in the MySQL Command Prompt using:

```
show variables like 'tmpdir';
```

the `tmpdir` is still assigned to `C:/Windows/Temp`. Can anybody tell me how to change the `tmpdir` inside the MySQL?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add it anywhere in the ini file under the [mysqld] section

e.g.
[mysqld]
tmpdir=d:/temp

Make sure the 'temp' folder is already created. I tried it and did work

Source: [Changing MySQL 5.0's tmp folder within my.ini in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060561/changing-mysql-5-0s-tmp-folder-within-my-ini-in-windows)

Comment: Please flag to close duplicate questions instead of answering them.  Stack Overflow doesn't need multiple pages with the same answers.

Comment: Thanks MickMackUsa, had no idea that was the strategy.