# mysql select query "No Space Left On Device"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

My system is using Ubuntu with mysql database:
I have a complex mysql select query to run.

```
mysql -u root -p  myDB < query.sql
```

But when I try to run it it always gives me:

> ERROR 3 (HY000) at line 1: Error writing file
>   '/mnt/disk/tmp/MY0Wy7vA' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)

I have 11 GB free on disk and while the query is running, I keep track of it using

```
df -h
```

and

```
df -hi
```

to keep track of inodes

and I don't see any decrease in disk space while the query is running. All the time there is always 11 GB free on disk where the tmp folder is located.

This is the output of `df -h`:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-177:~$ df -h  
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev  
tmpfs           799M   57M  742M   8% /run  
/dev/xvda1       30G   24G  5.4G  82% /  
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm  
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock  
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/xvdf1       50G   39G   11G  80% /mnt/disk  
tmpfs           799M     0  799M   0% /run/user/1000
```

This is the output of `df -aTh`:

> Filesystem     Type         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>   /dev/xvdf1     ext4          50G   39G   11G  80% /mnt/disk

Comment: Are you sure that partition has space? Is this your `/tmp` partition being full? What does `df -h` say?

Comment: Temporary storage permanently mounted at /mnt/disk? Really?

Comment: @tadman it is not full I updated the answer to view the result of df -h

Comment: You need to confirm which filesystem `/mnt/disk/tmp/` is on. Try `df -Ph /mnt/disk/tmp/`. Note that a query can create a temp table that is *very* large, and then as soon as the query finishes or is killed, the temp table is removed, so you run `df` and it looks like you have plenty of space.

Comment: It's worth noting that it can run out of space during an operation, then delete the temporary file, so unless you check `df` as it's running you won't be able to observe the problem. If you need to generate a >742MB file as part of an operation this will fail. Try `watch df -h` if you have (or can get) `watch` installed to monitor it as it's running.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the part of the error that indicate it’s actually writing to /tmp (see below)

```
: Error writing file '/mnt/disk/tmp/MY0Wy7vA
```

In some Linux distributions, /tmp is mounted as a tmpfs (ramdisk), so even if your disk has plenty of space you can get a "no space" error if you try to write too much there.

To investigate about the mount, try

```
$ cat /proc/mounts
```

OR
      $ cat /proc/self/mounts
Or better yet

```
df - aTh

df -h /tmp
```

To see hidden ones, try

du -sc * .[^.]* | sort -n

Among other things you can try making MySQL use a different temp directory, or to not use tmpfs for /tmp

If TMPDIR is not set in **my.cnf**, MySQL uses the system default which is usually /tmp

You can change the MySQL tmp dir as the following suggests:

[Changing the tmp folder of mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990887/changing-the-tmp-folder-of-mysql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Credits ::
https://github.com/LogBlock/LogBlock/issues/540

Comment: the partition is not tmpfs I added the output of df -h to my answer

Comment: Updated the answer, post output of  df - aTh

Comment: added the output of df -aTh